# Data Storage / organisation of a large scale website. How to organise?

Tags: database, storage, structure, media

I am currently experimenting with a website that will allow users to post music and photos. My initial thought was to have a global database of users that stores standard account information, each user would then be generated her own database that stores information on media uploaded, i.e. title/artist/file location. All media files will be stored in a separate system, and called upon when needed.

I am unsure about generating a database for each user... Is this the correct practice? Also what's the best way to make the media storage secure?

Comment: What are you using as a media storage? SQL/NoSQL database? How much data you think you are gonna have per user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't generate a new database for each user. It *may be* the right practice under some specific conditions, but generally it should be avoided.

Instead, use a reference to user identifier in each of your media entities. For instance, say we are using an SQL database which has two tables: `users` and `media`:

The users table looks something like this:

```
id     name          email
-----------------------------------------
1      John Doe      john.doe@example.com
2      Jane Doe      jane.doe@example.com
```

Similarly you have a media table with something like:

```
id     title         user_id
-------------------------
1      Nice picture  1
2      This too!     2
```

Now, just make sure `user_id` in `media` table is a foreign key that points to `id` field in `users` table.

In terms of security, you now need to make sure that when your user accesses data, she can only modify (or view) the data that she owns. For instance in order to return media owned by our user `Jane Doe`, you could query:

```
SELECT * FROM media WHERE user_id=2;
```

Comment: Ahhhh brilliant advice thank you I thought it was a bad idea :S Thanks!! Will this not get messy eventualy? Or is it just how it's done?

Comment: No problems :) Can you also answer my comment so I can provide more details? Also note that you can upvote and accept answers.

Comment: No worries, I've ticked it now (new the to forum.. obviously!) I'm using mysql for databases, php for serverside and I was just going to use a file system on a server to store data

Comment: Seems ok. Note the following: if you don't have that much data, you could also store it inside your SQL database (`BLOB` datatype). If you have A LOT of data or many files, local filesystem does not scale well -- in such case you might consider using some dedicated data storage (Amazon S3, MongoDB GridFS, etc.).

Comment: Also, enjoy your time at Stackoverflow.com! You can always ask new questions and even provide answers your self!

Comment: BRilliant thank you, I have a feeling it will be a long time before I can even comprehend answering other questions but I'll give it ago...